# Unable to Connect To GoogleFit

Tags: google-play-services, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to connect to Googlefit but i am getting a strange error code as below

**E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Unexpected error code 5005**

Does anybody have any idea about this.Thanks In advance

Comment: I am also having this issue, unfortunately.

Comment: Hey Brian,I don't know if there is any relation but the only thing I did before it started working was to fill the required fields in the Consent screen in the Developers Console.

Comment: hope this post may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582199/getting-error-in-google-fit-connection-failed-cause-connectionresultstatusco][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582199/getting-error-in-google-fit-connection-failed-cause-connectionresultstatusco

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the error with the help of the answer in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28391583/2977169

@Sumoanand:

I also faced similar problem.

```
This issue occurs if app is not registered properly in google developer console.
```

I think you have registered app on Google developer Console using production keystore certificate fingerprint(SHA1) where as you are testing it on app which has debug keystore.

Perform following steps:

```
Create one more client Id using debug keystore certificate fingerprint(SHA1).
Uninstall existing app.
Install app & connect to Google fit.
Check under google fit app & make sure that your app is listed as a connected app (... > Settings > Connected apps > Connected apps & devices).
Now run the above code & it will work !!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and the consent screen had been filled in correctly. The only way I could get around this was to delete the project and re-create it.

Comment: Did you change any settings or dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my device date time to past time before connect to Google Fit and I got error 5005.

After changed to current time, it works :)