# Getting error in google fit "Connection failed. Cause: ConnectionResult{statusCode=unknown status code 5005, resolution=null}"

Tags: google-api, google-play-services, android-5.0-lollipop, google-fit

I have tried to develop application using google fit.  I follow [This](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started) link

When i try to run that application i got the following error

10-27 11:55:19.966: I/Google Fit(6016): Connection failed. Cause: ConnectionResult{statusCode=unknown status code 5005, resolution=null}

10-27 11:55:19.966: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(6016): Unexpected error code 5005

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i found that issues. We need to save the content in consent screen under oath and api [image]

Comment: I don't understand your answer, what exactly did you do?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and the consent screen had been filled in correctly. The only way I could get around this was to delete the project and re-create it.

Comment: How did recreating the project fix this problem?

Comment: I fixed this error using this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28868460/2977169