# Connect with google fit api when not connected to internet

Tags: android, google-api-client, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am getting the following error when the mobile is not connected to internet while trying to build google api client to access the fit api: `connection failed. Cause: ConnectionResult{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}`. I have tried two way to connect with google fit api:

METHOD 1: This one connect with Fit API after signing in. This method does not work when there is no internet. I figure internet is needed for the signin procedure.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE), new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
            .build();

    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(failedListener)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.SESSIONS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
            .build();
```

METHOD 2: Hence I tried removing the signin feature, because I felt once the user has logged in and authorized fit api to collect data then signing in won't be essential.

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                    .addApi(Fitness.SESSIONS_API)
                    .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
                    .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(failedListener)
                    .build();
```

But I am getting this error in the connection failed listener `ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_FAILED, resolution=null, message=null}`.

How can I ensure that the fitApi can be accessed without internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following workaround:

- Check that your project has a product name and an email address associated with it, both to be found in the "consent screen" section.
- If it doesn't work, delete the project and re-create it.
- Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361874/unable-to-connect-to-googlefit/28868460#28868460), this issue occurs if app is not registered properly in google developer console.

> I think you have registered app on Google developer Console using
>   production keystore certificate fingerprint(SHA1) where as you are
>   testing it on app which has debug keystore.
>
> Perform following steps:
>
> 1. Create one more client Id using debug keystore certificate fingerprint(SHA1).
> 2. Uninstall existing app.
> 3. Install app & connect to Google fit.
> 4. Check under google fit app & make sure that your app is listed as a connected app (... > Settings > Connected apps > Connected apps &
>      devices).
> 5. Now run the above code & it will work !!!

Check these related tickets:

- [Error : ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280794/error-connectionresultstatuscode-internal-error-resolution-null)
- [Getting error in google fit "Connection failed. Cause: ConnectionResult{statusCode=unknown status code 5005, resolution=null}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582199/getting-error-in-google-fit-connection-failed-cause-connectionresultstatusco)
- [Unable to Connect To GoogleFit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361874/unable-to-connect-to-googlefit/28868460#28868460)

Hope this helps!