# Android Wear access Google Fit API

Tags: android, wear-os, google-api-client, google-fit, android-wear-2.0

I'm trying to access Google Fit API on Android Wear to get user Goals and I faced followed problem.

//I'm runing on Android Wear 2.0 emulator.

If there is no account specified (via setAccountName) in Builder, I get 
"Invalid Account" error message.

If i set manually account name I receive

> "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication has problem with availability of google play services. Try again.".

I used following code to do this:

```
     mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Fitness.GOAL_API)
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
                    .addConnectionCallbacks([...])
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(
                        new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                                    if (result.hasResolution()) {
                                        try {
                             result.startResolutionForResult(ConfigAccount.this, request_code);
                                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    } else {
    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(ConfigAccount.this, result.getErrorCode(), request_code_error, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {})
                    .build();
```

Every time the result.resolution in onConnectionFailed() is null.
Error code is 5005 - UNKNOWN_AUTH_ERROR
Because the resolution is null, the startResolutionOnResult and enableAutoManage does not work.

The credentials should be fine.
Presented approach works on phone with Android 5.1.

Version of play services is 9.8.0.
Downgrading the version didn't help.

Any Ideas how can I achieve my goal?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it took some time to answer, but in Android Wear Dev Preview 4, Google added [wear 2.0 authentication](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/auth-wear.html?utm_campaign=android%20wear_launch_developerpreview_121316&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog). It looks like other ways of login into google services are not supported on wearables.

Comment: Hello I am trying to use the fitness API with a wearable app, so I get from your answer that you have to sign in with google to access this API?

Answer (score 2):

From the `FitnessStatusCodes` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/FitnessStatusCodes), the `Error code is 5005 - UNKNOWN_AUTH_ERRO`R is a status code denotes that an unknown error occurred while trying to obtain an OAuth token. So make sure you get your OAuth token properly.

Another possible cause of this error occurs if your app is not registered properly in google developer console.

It is stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361874/unable-to-connect-to-googlefit) that you might have registered app on Google developer Console using production keystore certificate fingerprint(SHA1) where as you are testing it on app which has debug keystore.

Here are the steps that you need to do.

- Create one more client Id using debug keystore certificate fingerprint(SHA1).
- Uninstall existing app.
- Install app & connect to Google fit.
- Check under google fit app & make sure that your app is listed as a connected app (... > Settings > Connected apps > Connected apps & devices

For more information, check this [thread](https://plus.google.com/107156378235083529247/posts/NH9ErgKDpot) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582199/getting-error-in-google-fit-connection-failed-cause-connectionresultstatusco?rq=1).