# How to disable Google Fit and revoke permissions from the app itself

Tags: android, google-fit

I've setup app that connects to Google Fit, reads and writes some data about users body. When user disables Google Fit in apps settings, I try to revoke my apps permissions for by calling:

```
public void disableGoogleFit(){
    if(!mClient.isConnected()){
        Log.e(TAG, "Google Fit wasn't connected");
        return;
    }
    PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = Fitness.ConfigApi.disableFit(mClient);

    pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
            if(status.isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Google Fit disabled");
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "Google Fit wasn't disabled " + status);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Even though I could successfully read/write data, disabling Fit returns me error:

```
Google Fit wasn't disabled Status
{statusCode=unknown status code: 5010, resolution=null}
```

**Edit1:** Added whole method, in which its visible, that client is connected at the moment I try do disable Fit.

Comment: was your client connected at the time of call to disable ?

Comment: When authorized to access Fit, do you see your app listed in the Google Settings app under Google Fit > Connected apps and devices? If not, try stepping through steps for enabling the fitness API at:

https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started#step_3_enable_the_fitness_api

Comment: Hit the same issue, with an unpublished App i'm testing via USB. It functions as expected, and I was asked to authorise it's access initially, but this grant dosen't show in  [your account](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions). So wondering, from the comments, if a Google Fit authorised app only shows once published and public. If this is the case then may be the error will persist till it's a public published version.

Answer (score 8):

Currently with 15.0.1 lib it can be easily done:

```
fun disconnect(context: Context) {
    val fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_WORKOUT_EXERCISE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .build()
    val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder().addExtension(fitnessOptions).build()
    val client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, signInOptions)
    client.revokeAccess()
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but keep getting `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptionsExtension.getExtensionType()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Thanks mate, this one helped me to revoke permission dialog

Comment: .addExtension() was the fix in my case.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue if I revoked access on the Google Fit side of the operation as opposed to calling the disableFit() method. When using the disableFit() method, things got disconnected just fine and re-connecting was a cake walk. But When Google Fit revoked access it does not eliminate the existing OAuth and so you are stuck in limbo. Limbo being you are disconnected but no OAuth challenge is issued so you keep getting the 5010 error.

The only solution I came up with was to OAuth challenge by connecting to another account. Then you were fine. 
This sounds like an issue on Google Fit, however, and nothing on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced similar problem.

> This issue occurs if app is not registered properly in google
>   developer console.

I think you have registered app on Google developer Console using production keystore certificate fingerprint(SHA1) where as you are testing it on app which has debug keystore.

Perform following steps:

1. Create one more client Id using debug keystore certificate fingerprint(SHA1).
2. Uninstall existing app.
3. Install app & connect to Google fit.
4. Check under google fit app & make sure that your app is listed as a connected app (... > Settings > Connected apps > Connected apps & devices).
5. Now run the above code & it will work !!!

Answer (score 1):

Use this

Fitness.getConfigClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)).disableFit()

[Check here](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/disconnect)

Answer (score 0):

As per the Android developer forum

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/ConfigApi.html

> public static final int APP_NOT_FIT_ENABLED
>
> *Status code denotes that an app was not found in the list of connected
>   apps in Google Fit. Signifies that either access to the app was
>   already revoked, or the app is not registered on the developer's
>   console.*
>
> **Constant Value: 5010 (0x00001392)**

and to call a `disableFit`, **client must be connected at the time of the call**

```
public abstract PendingResult<Status> disableFit (GoogleApiClient client)
```

*Disables Google Fit for an app. Can be used to revoke all granted OAuth access permissions from an app and consequently remove all existing subscriptions and registrations of the app.*

**Parameters**

> **client**    an existing GoogleApiClient. **Must be connected at the time of
>   this call**.

Comment: As I've written in my question - client IS connected when I try to disconnect.

Comment: For debugging, can you try this `if(mClient.isConnected()) --> try disableFIT only then else print 'Client not connected'`

Answer (score 0):

After disabling call

```
mClient.disconnect();
```

Which is worked for me